# is copy constructor called automatically even when there isn't any object to be copied?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I found this piece of code on the net:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Line {
   public:
      int getLength( void );
      Line( int len );             // simple constructor
      Line( const Line &obj);  // copy constructor
      ~Line();                     // destructor

   private:
      int *ptr;
};

// Member functions definitions including constructor
Line::Line(int len) {
   cout << "Normal constructor allocating ptr" << endl;

   // allocate memory for the pointer;
   ptr = new int;
   *ptr = len;
}

Line::Line(const Line &obj) {
   cout << "Copy constructor allocating ptr." << endl;
   ptr = new int;
   *ptr = *obj.ptr; // copy the value
}

Line::~Line(void) {
   cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
   delete ptr;
}

int Line::getLength( void ) {
   return *ptr;
}

void display(Line obj) {
   cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}

// Main function for the program
int main( ) {
   Line line(10);

   display(line);

   return 0;
}
```

the result of executing this code was:

```
Normal constructor allocating ptr
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
Length of line : 10
Freeing memory!
Freeing memory!
```

I can't understand why copy constructor is called when there is no object that is passed as an argument to copy constructor?
also, while debugging, I understand that a destructor is called after function main finished. why it is called and why it is called after function main terminated??
thanks,

Comment: well you are calling the copy constructor here `display(line)`, it makes a copy because you pass the object by value here `display(Line obj)`

Comment: ... and usually "display" is defined as "void display(const Line& obj)". In this case a copy constructor is not called.

Comment: *I found this piece of code on the net:* -- You won't like it too much when you find out that `{Line ln(10); Line ln2(3); ln2 = ln;}` fails miserably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void display(Line obj) {
```

This function takes its parameter by value. This means that passing this parameter to this function will copy it. This is where your copy constructor gets called, when `main()`  calls `display()`.

If you change this function so that it takes its parameter by reference:

```
void display(Line &obj) {
```

You will find that the copy constructor no longer gets called, from your sample program.

You will find more information about passing parameters by value versus reference in your C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

The function display takes it's argument by value, hence the copy constructor is called.  If that is not wanted, pass it by reference - Line & obj.  Better yet, call it by const reference - const Line & obj.  But in the latter case, the member function you call inside of display would have to be const also.

Answer (score 0):

The argument in `display()`:

```
void display(Line obj)
```

Invokes the copy constructor, as a new object is being made in the argument of the function. Therefore, any object of class `Line` that you pass to this function will be copied and used as a perameter for the function body.

You invoke this function in the following line:

```
display(line);
```

As a result, a copy of `line` is made in `display()`. To avoid this, reference an object of class `Line` instead. Change the way the argument is passed in the function header to:

```
void display(Line &obj)
```

This way, you are only referencing the object, hence, not making a copy of it. Therefore, the copy constructor will not be invoked here.